# For Loop - print operand divided by two

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

I've been given a for loop statement which I must replace the '???' so that the code prints 80,40,20,10,5.

```
for (??? ; ??? ; ??? ) { 
System.out.println(i); 
}
```

I've tried

```
for (int i = 80 ; i>=5 ; i/2) { 
System.out.println(i); 
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work, I'm not sure how to proceed. I can't add any additional statements, I must only use the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `i/2` to `i` so that the value of `i` can change in each iteration.

Do it as follows:

```
for (int i = 80 ; i>=5 ; i = i/2) { 
    if (i > 5) {
        System.out.print(i + ","); 
    } else {
        System.out.print(i); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation: You forgot to assign `i/2` to anything. `i /= 2` would have worked as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Schred for the comment. I was already typing it but now I'll leave it. Hopefully, OP will check your comment as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it should be done based on your data and question. This makes use of the ternary operator `?:` which is worth knowing about.

```
for (int i = 80; i >= 5; i/=2) {
    System.out.print(i > 5 ? i + "," : i +"\n" );
}
```